# PostgreSQL join with similar address

Tags: postgresql, inner-join, street-address

I am trying to join data from disparate sources. The only common field to join is address. In table 1 , address has extra data (representing neighborhood) between street and state. Is there a way to join these tables using most similar address? I have 85,000 addresses, so a manual search using LIKE and wildcards will not work.

Table 1:
"239 Dudley St Dudley Square Roxbury MA 02119"
"539 Dudley St Dudley Square Roxbury MA 02119"

Table 2:
"239 Dudley St Roxbury MA 02119"
"539 Dudley St Roxbury MA 02119"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two suggestions:

1) "All words in the table 2 address are present in the table 1 address":

```
select *
from t1 join
  t2 on (string_to_array(t2.address,' ') <@ string_to_array(t1.address,' '));
```

2) "For each table 1 address find the most similar address from the table 2":

```
select distinct on(t1.address) *
from t1 cross join t2
order by t1.address, similarity(t1.address, t2.address) desc;
```